# UILabel first text overlaps second text

Tags: objective-c

I am doing signup page's uitextfields validation programmatically. I have given a single label separately under signup button where it shows the error message.

I have given first name text wrong so that label shows "Please enter valid first name" and I have done the same with Last name and now the message "Please enter valid second name" overlaps the  first name error message.

How to get two error messages separately using single label?

Comment: How are you writing that second message to the label (please show that part of the code)? I suspect you are replacing the message, instead of appending to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can just change the text of the label while showing the Error message

For Eg:

```
if (**firstNameTextWrong**)
{
lbl.text=@"Please enter valid first name";
}
else if (**secondNameTextWrong**)
{ 
lbl.text=@"Please enter valid second name";
}
else
{
//do the right part here
[lbl setHidden:YES];
}
```